# Getting the latest source from TFS through the command line

Tags: tfs, command-line-interface, tf-cli

I'm trying to grab a project from TFS from the command line.  I have its location on the server (starts with `$/`) and a directory I want to put it in.

I navigate to that directory, type `tf workspace /new /s:<servername>`, and enter a workspace name.

Next I type `tf get /force /recursive /version:W<workspacename>`, it returns 'All files are up to date', however it hasn't downloaded anything.

Also, I'd like to download the project into the workspace directory and then `<projectname>`, currently it makes a bunch of folders (based on `$/the/long/path/to/the/<projectname>` on the server).

Is there a way I can do that or do I need to move it after I'm done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also have to map the folders.  Take a look at `tf workfold`

```
tf workfold /map:"$/ServerFolder/Path/To/Map","C:\LocalFolder\Path" /workspace:WorkspaceName /server:http://tfs:8080
```

Substitute anything in that command line that follows a colon into the correct value for your environment.

Also, you can map at any level that you want.  For instance, you could map `$/Project/Folder/Project1/Source` to `C:\TFSSource\Project1`

Comment: cool, it looks like that (`tf workfold`) will solve the long path issue, but even after doing that I still get `All files are up to date` when trying to do `tf get /force /recursive /s:<servername> /version:W<workflowname>`, how can I fix that?

Comment: Don't use the /version: parameter, and make sure to run the tf get from within the local folder that is mapped.